How to enable on-the-go builds in Visual Studio Community 2022
I am writing an application on Avalonia UI in Visual Studio Community 2022. However, as of recently I have encountered a problem.  For example, I am writing code in a ViewModel file.
[ObservableProperty] private string? _title;

This attribute (ObservableProperty) shortens your code very much, namely instead of writing
public string Title
{
    get => title;
    set => SetProperty(ref isEnabled, value)
}

I can write   [ObservableProperty] private string? _title;  and with the help of ObservableProperty the public property Title is automatically generated and I used to be able to use it immediately in methods, but now I have to compile the application first and only then VS sees this property, I don't have such problems in Rider, but I don't like Rider very much, is there any way to fix it?
I searched for such an option in the settings but found nothing
sorry for my english

Check similar issue

I read it and realized it's not about my problem at all, especially since it doesn't give any details.

I thought it is close. Everything is around Source Gnerators.

In the article Visual Studio 2022 – Recent performance enhancements (October 1st, 2024) Microsoft explains how you can change the behavior of Source Generators.
In the menu Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Source Generators you can change the setting:
Source generator execution (requires restart)
from

Balanced, Run generators after saving or building

to

Automatic. Run generators after any change.

Note that this change may have an impact on the performance of Visual Studio 2022 (Version >= 17.11).
